# Exit from the recursion stack in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

Is there any way to totally exit from the recursion stack in c++. For example I am searching for some goal state using recussion and when I found that just print it and come out from all the recussion stack.

Comment: You mean there is no way to end up all the recussion stack at once....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this (whether this is stylistically the best is questionable) is likely via wrapping your recursive function in a `try`/`catch` block, and then exiting via throwing a custom exception of some sort that contains the results of your calculation.  This will automatically unwind your stack to the level of your `try`/`catch` block, and then you can proceed from there.

Comment: Interesting but dangerous if there are resources that should be cleaned up along the way and RAII is not being used. (or not used propery)

Comment: I think this is stylistically appropriate.

Comment: @Dave: Absolutely!  You'd have to ensure it was safe before using this kind of technique.

Answer (score 2):

An exception would unwind the stack, but that would typically be a bad choice.  Using an exception for flow control is probably not wise.  Maintenance could be more difficult particularly if someone else has to update the code and is not aware of the exit via exception.  The best choice is to return gracefully from each level.

Comment: Sure, it's unconventional, but unwise? I thought the whole point of exceptions is that they ARE graceful because they can be caught, manipulated, etc.

Comment: If someone else is not aware of it and, for example, adds logic that requires some cleanup, then the cleanup might not occur.  Maybe it is simply a matter of taste, but an exception seems a poor choice for flow control to me.

Comment: Exceptions should be used for exceptional situations.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions make that quite simple, throwing and catching an exception lets you jump out of many stack frames at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception,
but with tail recursion there won't be a "recursion stack"

Answer (score 0):

You can use exceptions, of course, that will unwind the stack and run apropriately the destructors of local variables.

Or you can use old good `setjmp/longjmp`, that will not run the destructors. IIRC, it will result in undefined behavior if there are any missed destructors.